# How to show all rows in listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have an asp.net web form and listview on it. I want to take data from a SQL Server table using linq .

But when I see result I can't see rows with sample first field (id of person).

How can I display all results ?

In my SQL Server table I see it like this:
**UPDATED**
    id  name    Change Date       Status  Actual
    0  John    2016-05-10 00:00   Status1  0
    0  John    2016-05-10 00:00  Status2  1
    1  Jel     2016-03-10 00:00  Status3  1
    2  Andrew  2016-01-10 00:00  Status4  0
    2  Andrew  2016-03-10 19:30  Status2  1
    3  Kozh    2016-03-10 19:30  Status1  1
    4  Ars     2016-03-10 19:30  Status1  1
    5  Oser    2016-03-10 19:30  Status1  0
    5  Oser    2016-03-10 19:30  Status2  1

And when I show page I see only first two rows

My code:

```
      <asp:ListView ID="ListView2" ItemType="DocCat.Models.ReqInf" SelectMethod="GetData
            DataKeyNames="ID" EnableViewState="false"  runat="server" visible="true"
                   UpdateMethod="ListView2_UpdateItem"   >
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <div class="outerContainer">
                    <table id="docTable">
                        <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>ChangeStatus</th>
                            <th>Change Date</th>
 </tr>
                        <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder"></tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate >
                <tr>
                         <td><%# Item.ID %></td>
             <td><%# Item.F1%></td>
             <td><%# Item.ChangeS %></td>
            <td><%# Item.ChangeD  %></td></tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:ListView>
```

Code :

```
public IEnumerable<ReqInf> GetReq()
{
    IEnumerable<ReqInf> docsu = repository.ReqForDoc;
return  docsu.OrderBy(I => I.ID)
}
```

Asp.Net Webforms, Entity Framework

**UPDATE**
RESULT :
    1  Jel     2016-03-10 00:00  Status3  1
    3  Kozh    2016-03-10 19:30  Status1  1
    4  Ars     2016-03-10 19:30  Status1  1
    5  Oser    2016-03-10 19:30  Status2  1

**UPDATE**
I use EFDB context .

```
   public DbSet<ReqInf> ReqForDoc { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                modelBuilder.Entity<ReqInf>().ToTable("ReqForDoc");
            }
```

And Repository

```
public IEnumerable<ReqInf> ReqForDoc
        {
            get { return context.ReqForDoc; }
        }
```

Comment: If you are seeing two rows then the height of the listview is too small to see all four rows.

Comment: The last two rows are not distinct. May be you have some logic to show only distinct rows. If possible post your business code.

Comment: @Vicky_Thinking When i change my row i need to save it and make another row with different date and status . i need to have logs , because of that i need to see all rows with same id.

Comment: @jdweng i have pagination , and i have more rows than 4 , it just for sample

Comment: @АндрейГолубцов got your point and it's fair. Your posted code looks fine to me. Could please post linq query and binding to the listview?

Comment: @Vicky_Thinking . I add all code, hope you can see what i've doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a day i understand that my problem isn't in code. 
I have a column ID , and EF automatically recognize it like a key attribute. But, key must be unique , and I :

- **Renamed ID column**
- **Added [Key] Attribute to a unique property (`ChangeDate` in my case)**

My code addition in Model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
 namespace Project.Models
        {
            public class BaseClass
            {
                [Key]
                public DateTime ChangeDate { get; set; }
    ...
```